# Datatables get value fron a cell that have an input

Tags: jquery, datatables, filtering

Ok, i'm trying to build a custom search, on my Datatables, i have a problem when i try to filter a column that have a `select`inside it.

the problem start when i filter with the column `11` that have the next syntax:

```
<select> 
    <option value="1">1</option> 
    <option value="2">2</option> 
    <option value="3">3</option> 
    <option value="4">4</option> 
    <option value="5" selected="">5</option>
</select>
```

i use the next function to build a custom filter:

```
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function ( settings, data, dataIndex) {
            dataFromFormat = getDataFromFormat( data[11] ); //return 1 2 3 4 5
            stringLike( dataFromFormat, $('#customSearch').val() )
        }
    );



function stringLike(string, substring){
    if (string.indexOf(substring) !== -1) return true
    else return false;
}



function getDataFromFormat(datavalue){
    console.log(datavalue);
    if ( $(datavalue).is('a') ){
        console.log('a');
        return $(datavalue).text();

    } else if ( $(datavalue).is('input') ){
        console.log('input');
        return $(datavalue).val();

    } else if ( $(datavalue).is('select') ){
        console.log('select');
        return $(datavalue).val();

    } else {
        console.log('only text'); //enter here, because data[11] doesn't have the select syntax only the text contained in it (1 2 3 4 5)
        return datavalue;
    }
}
```

but when i check what i have in my `data[11]` every time it returns:

```
1  2 3 4 5
```

only the text content, but not the HTML tags, and nothing, it should return the `select` itself, because that's the real content of the column 11.

How can i get the real content, or, how can i get the value from the `select`

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle with a working example so we can debug/find a solution.

Comment: Sounds weird, cannot replicate the behavior at all. Even as plain string `$(datavalue).val()` should (and will) return the value of the selected option. BTW, `selected=""` should just be `selected` ie `<option value="5" selected>5</option>` (but that is not the reason)

Comment: `data[11]` is the problem, when Datatable returns the `data` the field 11 (`data[11]`) should contain the `select` but only contains `1 2 3 4 5` that i think it's only the text. That's why, when it enter to `getDataFromFormat()` never enter to the `if ( $(datavalue).is('select') )` it enter to the `only text` if.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to extract the values entered in the input boxes, you must go through jQuery or native DOM. dataTables itself is not aware of any changes made to form input fields, so trying to retrieve the values by cell().data() will never work, with or without id's / orthogonal data :

aTable.cell(0,2).nodes().to$().find('input').val()
aTable.cell(0,3).nodes().to$().find('input').val()
Will give you the current value of the various inputs. Have replicated your above scenario 100% in this fiddle ->

```
http://jsfiddle.net/obmghyo7/
```

This is basically also how the official documentation suggests a way to extract values from form inputs ->

```
https://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html
```

If you want to perform filtering / searches within the table, which also includes changes made by the user in form inputs, then it is a little more tricky -> JQuery Datatables search within input and select (mine, but I dont know any better answer)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're using `return $(datavalue).val();` in both of your `else if` statements. This will return the `value` from your `select` which is why you get `1 2 3 4 5` since these are the values (e.g., `value=1`) for your select.

I'm not sure what the content is in your selects, but you should be able to use `return $(datavalue).text();` or `return $(datavalue).html();`

```
function getDataFromFormat(datavalue){
    console.log(datavalue);
    if ( $(datavalue).is('a') ){
        console.log('a');
        return $(datavalue).text();

    } else if ( $(datavalue).is('input') ){
        console.log('input');
        return $(datavalue).text();

    } else if ( $(datavalue).is('select') ){
        console.log('select');
        return $(datavalue).text();

    } else {
        console.log('only text'); //enter here, because data[11] doesn't have the select syntax only the text contained in it (1 2 3 4 5)
        return datavalue;
    }
}
```

OR

```
function getDataFromFormat(datavalue){
    console.log(datavalue);
    if ( $(datavalue).is('a') ){
        console.log('a');
        return $(datavalue).text();

    } else if ( $(datavalue).is('input') ){
        console.log('input');
        return $(datavalue).html();

    } else if ( $(datavalue).is('select') ){
        console.log('select');
        return $(datavalue).html();

    } else {
        console.log('only text'); //enter here, because data[11] doesn't have the select syntax only the text contained in it (1 2 3 4 5)
        return datavalue;
    }
}
```